# Is it correct to write: "I versus my family"

Tags: writing

Is it correct to write:  "I versus my family"

Comment: 'Myself versus my family.'

Comment: No, that sentence has no verb.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. "Correct" requires context— what situation are you trying to describe, and what would the full sentence or dialogue be? Second, our standards indicate questions should identify the problem and describe your initial research attempts— what exactly do you think might be wrong, and how have you attempted to confirm or deny that suspicion? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Well, the equivalent i.e. *I against my family* sounds weird to me.

Comment: I would write, "It's me, verses the family".  But I don't know grammar so I have no idea if this is correct.